# How to trap Error ERROR: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. in Powershell Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I have  created an Azure Devops Pipeline and created Powershell script which run in ServiceConnection Context. This Service Connection is Azure ServicePrincipal.

```
$groupName =  "ABC"
$res = (az ad group list --display-name $groupName)

Write-Host "Response " $res
```

When i execute pipeline i get this Error message

ERROR: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

However $res is null.

How do i trap this error message in my powershell code?

Comment: After the `az ad` call, try to check if `$LASTEXITCODE` is non-zero, e. g. `if( $LASTEXITCODE -ne 0 ) { 'TODO: handle error' }`

Comment: It looks like the error is written to _stderr_, so if you want to check for the error message, redirect _stderr_ to _stdout_ using `2>&1`, e. g.: `$stdout, $stderr = (az ad group list --display-name $groupName 2>&1).Where({$_ -is [string]}, 'Split')`. The `$stderr` variable will be an array of `ErrorRecord`, which you can convert to string using its `.ToString()` method.

Comment: @zett42  your answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the error is written to *stderr*, so if you want to check for the error message, redirect *stderr* to *stdout* using the redirection operator `2>&1`:

```sh
$stdout, $stderr = (az ad group list --display-name $groupName 2>&1).Where({$_ -is [string]}, 'Split') 

if( $stderr -like '*Insufficient privileges to complete the operation*' ) {
   # Handle the error
}
```

- Using the [redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2) `2>&1` the error stream (aka *stderr*) is merged into the success stream (aka *stdout*), so we can treat them in a unified way.
- Using the group operator `(…)`, a *temporary* array is created from the streams.
- Using the *intrinsic* [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#where) method, we split up this array into two variables, depending on the stream type.
- If there are any messages written to *stdout*, the `$stdout` variable is an array of strings.
- If there are any messages written to *stderr*, the `$stderr` variable is an array of [`ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0).
- The `-like` operator acts as a filter when LHS argument is a collection, which outputs only the matching elements. If there are any matching elements, the result converts to `$true` otherwise it converts to `$false` in a boolean context.
- PowerShell automatically converts the `ErrorRecord` to `string` when using the string comparison operator `-like`.