# Muting the 'System Error: Not implemented' output of 7zip in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I'm running 7-zip in a script and capturing the output in a variable:

```
$Results = (7z a $OutputFileName $InputFolder -bt -mm=LZMA -tzip) #will run and return no output
```

Occasionally the script will select some parameters that are not compatible, e.g. setting LZMA2 compression to a .zip archive:

```
$Results = (7z a $OutputFileName $InputFolder -bt -mm=LZMA2 -tzip)
```

when this runs, 7-zip somehow escapes the variable binding and writes directly to the console:

```
 System ERROR: 
 Not implemented
```

How do I find the error stream that 7-zip is writing to and capture/suppress it?

Comment: how about fixing the root cause (faulty parameters)?! to suppress anything you can do ```[void](7z a $OutputFileName $InputFolder -bt -mm=LZMA2 -tzip)```

Comment: @Toni Each parameter is stored as an array. I'm running nested `foreach` commands on the array to cycle through every possible option. e.g. `$ProtocolArray = ("Deflate","Deflate64","LZMA","PPMd","BZip2","LZMA2","BCJ","BCJ2")` The end goal is to determine the most space/time efficient settings. I don't know which settings are incompatible, so I figured trying every one, and those that are incompatible are thrown out of the results. I don't want to void the entire output, I just want to suppress the error message appearing.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73909728/7571258) for an example to capture the error stream in a separate variable.

Comment: @zett42 Took a minute, but that did the trick. Thanks for the help.